# MS Graph Beta Behavior - How to get Interactive and Non-Interactive signin Logs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

**Issue**: In order to retrieve all 4 signIn event types, we are using the Beta API to query the auditLog endpoint.  When this endpoint is queried without a filter on the signInEventTypes field, they only get those with a value of interactiveUser.  However, if we add a filter to exclude interactiveUser, they get all of the 3 other types of signInEventTypes.

**Question**: Is this expected behavior that is not documented in the Beta API documentation?

The following query only returns events with a signInEventTypes value of 'interactiveUser'.https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?%24filter=createdDateTime+ge+2024-01-25T15%3A12%3A59Z&%24orderby=createdDateTime

In order to see the other events with all possible signInEventTypes, we have to run the following additional query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=signInEventTypes/any(x:x
ne 'interactiveUser')+and+createdDateTime+ge+2023-11-13&$orderby=createdDateTime+asc&$top=50

**QUESTIONS**

1. Since this is a Beta API, is this a known/expected issue or not with the endpoint I’m calling?  If it is, is it possible to file a bug so that it can be addressed before the API goes GA.
2. Is there any anticipated date for GA of the current Beta API?  It adds a number of data elements over the 1.0 API that the we really want to ingest into their SIEM solution.  And while we know we can get them via an EventHub, the preference is for a real-time API as it avoids the overhead, duplication and potential failure point of an EventHub.

The issue is reproducible everytime